# How can i delete from list while using ransack search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i am trying to delete from list but when i am trying this it is getting deleted from database

```
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])    
  @search = Lesson.search(params[:q])     
  @lessons = @search.result.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)            
  @search.build_condition if @search.conditions.empty?     
  @course.lessons.each do |lesson|      
    @lessons.each do |l|        
      if lesson.id == l.id
        @lessons.delete(l) 
     end    
    end     
  end
```

I am getting this error: delete_all doesn't support limit scope
Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

Delete is an ActiveRecord method. I assume you don't want to delete it from the database but from the result list. You can do it like this:

```
@course.lessons.each do |lesson|
  @lesson.reject { |l| l.id == lesson.id }
end
```